# How to get to object properties when I have interface thru I'm passing arguments?

Tags: c#, oop

Can you guys explain me how can I get object properties when I have arguments who are interface type?

```
    public interface IObject {}

    public class Object : IObject {}
```

And then I have some methods like this :

```
    public void Add(IObject object)
    {
        object.someThing; // I want to get that property but I can't.
    }
```

What type should I use to get these properties? What's best practice?

Comment: Move the properties to the interface.

Comment: It's good to keep properties in interface?

Comment: @ext it's almost the entire purpose of an interface.

Comment: If you want to access members of the concrete class, type the variable `object` as `Object` (use the concrete type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Interface is a contract to be implemented by a class, which means

> whatever rules ( methods and properties ) that the interface contains
>   will need to be implemented by the classes that implement the
>   interface

So, when you accept a method with an interface as the type in the parameter, you are stating that the object that will be passed to the method will contain methods and properties as stated by the interface.

Hence, the methods that you wish to invoke on the object should be defined in the interface.